# Appending a pointer to a Slice in Golang

Tags: variables, pointers, go, slice

I want to append a pointer to a slice.Is it possible..?In Partentnode.children is a slice I want to append it with X as pointer.

https://play.golang.org/p/ghWtxWGOAU

```
func Tree(Parentnode *Node) {
    if IsvisitedNode(Parentnode.currentvalue - 1) {
        m := MovesArray[Parentnode.currentvalue-1]
        for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {
            if m[j] != 0 {
                var X *Node
                X.parentnode = Parentnode
                X.currentvalue = m[j]
                if IsvisitedNode(m[j]) {
                    Parentnode.children = append(Parentnode.children, *X)
                    Tree(X)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Index `j` does not exist in slice `m`. I would add some print statements to see where it goes wrong..

Comment: Also `for j := 0; j < 8; j++ {` -> `m[j]` is asking for trouble if you are not absolutly sure of `m` having 8 or more indices. Better is `for currval := range m {`

Comment: In the variable m there are definitely 8  values, including zeros for negative positions that is why i included the statement m[j]!=0. @RickyA

Answer (score 1):

You have a off by one error.
In main you set `Y.currentvalue = 1`.
Then in `Tree` currentvalue walks to `64`.

```
X.currentvalue = m[j]
fmt.Printf("cv: %v\n",X.currentvalue) //walks to 64
if IsvisitedNode(m[j]) {
```

An in `IsvisitedNode` you test that index against `visithistory` that has 64 indexes, thus stops at index 63. -> index error

```
var visithistory [64]bool

func IsvisitedNode(position int) bool {
    if visithistory[position] == true {
```

Things work if you set `var visithistory [65]bool` but I think you need to rethink you logic here somewhat.

Comment: That is the reason I use currentvalue-1 for IsVisitedNode function. @RickyA

Comment: I did try that but the Program exits after Printing just the three values.

Comment: of witch the last is 64, that is not a valid index in `visithistory` because the last index there is 63.